# Sharepoint Designer 2010 - Site workflow and list workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2010,
I have created **site worklow** from the designer.

1. How can I operate this workflow if site workflow do not associate to a list?
2. How can I convert a site workflow to a list workflow?

Answer (score 2):

From [Improvements in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335710.aspx) by Paul Andrew:

> You can get to the activated site workflows by choosing Site Workflows
>   from the Site Actions menu in SharePoint. It shows you new workflows
>   you can start, any running site workflows and completed workflows.
>   Since site workflows don’t have a list item or document to start from,
>   they must be started manually through the SharePoint user interface or
>   via the SharePoint API.

I don't think it is possible to change site workflow to list workflow (maybe some workaround exist).
To have more flexibility you can design Reusable workflows as described in Options for [Deploying Reusable Workflows in SharePoint 2010](http://gvaro.wordpress.com/2010/12/11/options-for-deploying-reusable-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010/) by Geoff Varosky.

Comment: can you **please** explain me step by step how to activated manually site workflow?

Comment: [Start a workflow instance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662540.aspx#site) you have step-by-step description there.

Answer (score 0):

Site Workflows are started through the SharePoint web UI by going to **View All Site Contents** and then click on the **Site Workflows**.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-2010Starting-Site-Workflows-Programmatically.aspx) is what you need to do if you are looking to start the site workflow programmatically.