# how manually activate site workflow in sharepoint designer 2010?

Tags: workflow, feature-activation, site

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharepoint Designer 2010 - Site workflow and list workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19947/sharepoint-designer-2010-site-workflow-and-list-workflow)

I have creted site workflow from the sharepoint designer.

(it is not possible to activate site workflow from list becuse It's not impossible to associate site workflow to a list).

so I want to activate this workflow manually.

**is someone can explain me step by step how to manually activate site workflow?**